# No module named 'graphviz' in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, graphviz

I tried to draw a decision tree in Jupyter Notebook this way.

```
mglearn.plots.plot_animal_tree()
```

But I didn't make it in the right way and got the following error message.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-45733bae690a> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 mglearn.plots.plot_animal_tree()

~\Desktop\introduction_to_ml_with_python\mglearn\plot_animal_tree.py in plot_animal_tree(ax)
      4 
      5 def plot_animal_tree(ax=None):
----> 6     import graphviz
      7     if ax is None:
      8         ax = plt.gca()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphviz
```

So I downloaded [Graphviz Windows Packages](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html) and installed it.

And I added the PATH installed path(C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin) to USER PATH and (C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe) to SYSTEM PATH.

And restarted my PC. But it didnt work. I still can't get it working.

So I searched over the internet and got another solution that, I can add the PATH in my code like this.

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin'
```

But it didn't work.
So I do not know how to figure it out now.

I use the Python3.6 integrated into Anacode3.

And I ALSO tried installing graphviz via PIP like this.

```
pip install graphviz
```

BUT it still doesn't work.

Hope someone can help me, sincerely.

Comment: What does `pip install graphviz` print? Do you use Python-2.x or Python-3.x? (normally the package manager for Python-3.x is `pip3`).

Comment: The result is that this problem has been fixed Inexplicably after restarting PC again. I used pip3 default and graphviz is in the pip list. So, I am really puzzled the problem how to solve... :(

Comment: hmm... Did you *restart* the jupyter-notebook after installing the package?

Comment: Yes, I did it many times. I don't know which one fixed the problem, the Graphviz installed by me or the other one got piped in command.  :(

Answer (score 77, accepted):

in Anaconda install

- python-graphviz
- pydot

This will fix your problem

Comment: Thanks ! , had the same problem . Saved me another half a day . Python newbie here .

Comment: I cannot help but make a comment of appreciation here... Thank you so much for your astonishing solution. You saved another half a day of someone.

Comment: thnks it worked out but throws new error - "AssertionError: "dot" with args ['-Tps', 'C:\\Users\\ASHISH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpu7mqu24b'] returned code: 1"

Comment: Not sure that `pydot` is actually required here, unless `mglearn` actually uses it. I'm not using `mglearn` so I'm not sure. In any case, for the general errors with a missing `graphviz`, it's only necessary to install `python-graphviz`.

Answer (score 17):

As @grrr answered above, here is the code:

```
conda install -c anaconda python-graphviz

conda install -c anaconda pydot
```

Answer (score 6):

In case if your operation system is **Ubuntu** I recommend to try command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y graphviz libgraphviz-dev
```

Answer (score 4):

I installed the grphviz package using conda. However, I kept getting "module not found error" even after restart kernel multiple times.

I even tried installing "PyDot", as suggested on this page, however, it didn't really help.

Finally, I installing the package using

```
pip install graphviz
```

worked and now I can import it without errors.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question has already been answered, but for future readers, I came here with the same jupyter notebook issue; after installing python-graphviz and pydot I still had the same issue. Here's what worked for me: Make sure that the python version of your terminal matches that of the jupyter notebook, so run this both in python in your terminal and then in your juypter notebook. If you are using a conda environment, load the environment before checking the python version.

`import sys`

`print(sys.version)`

If they do not match, i.e. python 3.6.x vs python 3.7.x then give your jupyter notebook the ability to find the version of python you want.

`conda install nb_conda_kernels`

`conda install ipykernel`

and if you are using a conda environment,

`python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv--display-name "Python (myenv)"`

where `myenv` is the name of your environment. Then go into your jupyter notebook, and in kernel -> change kernel, select the correct version of python. Fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You can install graphviz from here: https://graphviz.org/download/
it will set the PATH correctly and you can use it from jupyter notebook. No need to deal with the Anaconda environment.